# Nothing popping up on button click, no console messages[Clarified.]

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason some of my `console.log`'s aren't going through. The button doesn't seem to work and I think I'm making dumb mistakes cause I'm tired. What am I missing here? I'm totally lost- any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```js
function Count() {
          
        var newCount = 0
        
        if(document.toppings.Pepperoni.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Onion.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Sausage.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Mushrooms.checked)
        {newCount = newCount +1}
        if(document.toppings.Peppers.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Olives.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Garlic.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        
        if(newCount >= 4)
        {
            alert("Only 3 Toppings, Please");
            document.toppings;return false;
        }
      }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Variables
      var crust;
      var sauce;
      var smallPrice;
      var medPrice;
      var largePrice;
      var topPrice = 0;
      var finalTotal;
      
      $("#total").click(function() {
        // Size
        var size = $('input:radio[name=size]:checked').val();
          
        if(size === undefined) {
            alert("What Size Pizza? Please pick an option."); }
          
        // Sauce
        sauce = $('input:radio[name=sauce]:checked').val();
          
        if(sauce === undefined) {
            alert("What Sauce Would You Like? Please pick an option."); }
          
        // Crust Type
        crust = $('input:radio[name=crust]:checked').val();
          
        if(crust === undefined) {
            alert("What Crust Type? Please pick an option."); }
        
        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 12;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 14;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 16;
           }
            return smallPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 15;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 17;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 21;
           }
            return medPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 18;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 21;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 26;
           }
            return largePrice;
        }
        
        //Calculating Toppings
        
        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 1;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 2;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 3;
           }
            return topPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 2;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 4;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 6;
           }
            return topPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 3;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 6;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 9;
           }
            return topPrice;
        }
        
        // Calculating the Final Cost with toppings
        
        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (smallPrice + topPrice);
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (medPrice + topPrice);
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (largePrice + topPrice);
        }
            console.log("s " + smallPrice);
            console.log("m " + medPrice);
            console.log("l " + largePrice);
            console.log("top " + topPrice);
            console.log("final " + finalTotal);
            
            $("#msgHere").html("Your Total is: $ " + finalTotal);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Radio Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p>
    Pick A Size<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" id="Small"required>Small<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium" id="Medium">Medium<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" id="Large">Large<br/>
    </p>
    </form>
    
    <form>
    <p>
    Pick A Crust<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Thin">Thin<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Regular">Regular<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Deep-dish">Deep-dish<br/>
    </p>
    </form>
    
    <form>
    <p>
    Pick A Sauce<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="Red">Red<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="White">White<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="Green">Green<br/>
    </p>
    </form>
    
    <form name="toppings">
    <p>
    Pick Your Toppings (No More Than 3)<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Pepperoni" onClick="return Count()">Pepperoni<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Onion" onClick="return Count()">Onion<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sausage" onClick="return Count()">Sausage<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Mushrooms" onClick="return Count()">Mushrooms<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Peppers" onClick="return Count()">Peppers<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Olives" onClick="return Count()">Olives<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Garlic" onClick="return Count()">Garlic<br/>
    </p>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="total" value="Click For Your Total">
    <p id="msgHere"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. In this case, you managed to link to a fiddle against the rules of SO. Please click the `<>` and post the code here with a PROPER explanation of what the issues are. Your question is SUPER vague as it stand now

Comment: Start by pressing F12 and see you have `<script type="text/javascript">` INSIDE the script

Comment: Then medPrice is not defined, it's called mediumPrice

Comment: Then finalCost is called finalTotal elsewhere

Comment: Remove `<script type="text/javascript">` and its ending tag from your script in the fiddle to show up alerts

Comment: Then your fiddle needs to be set to "bottom of head" instead of "on load

Comment: Lastly you do not have anything with ID Large, Medium or Small

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, im running it internally and I completely forgot to take that out when making the fiddle

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: `document.toppings;`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Radio Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>
            Pick A Size<br />
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small" id="Small" required>Small<br />
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium" id="Medium">Medium<br />
            <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large" id="Large">Large<br />
        </p>
    </form>

    <form>
        <p>
            Pick A Crust<br />
            <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Thin" id="Thin">Thin<br />
            <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Regular" id="Regular">Regular<br />
            <input type="radio" name="crust" value="Deep-dish" id="Deep-dish">Deep-dish<br />
        </p>
    </form>

    <form>
        <p>
            Pick A Sauce<br />
            <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="Red" id="Red">Red<br />
            <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="White" id="White">White<br />
            <input type="radio" name="sauce" value="Green" id="Green">Green<br />
        </p>
    </form>

    <form name="toppings">
        <p>
            Pick Your Toppings (No More Than 3)<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Pepperoni" onClick="return Count()">Pepperoni<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Onion" onClick="return Count()">Onion<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Sausage" onClick="return Count()">Sausage<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Mushrooms" onClick="return Count()">Mushrooms<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Peppers" onClick="return Count()">Peppers<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Olives" onClick="return Count()">Olives<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="Garlic" onCount="return Count()">Garlic<br />
        </p>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="total" value="Click For Your Total">
    <p id="msgHere"></p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Count() {
        var newCount = 0
        if(document.toppings.Pepperoni.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Onion.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Sausage.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Mushrooms.checked)
        {newCount = newCount +1}
        if(document.toppings.Peppers.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Olives.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}
        if(document.toppings.Garlic.checked)
        {newCount = newCount + 1}

        if(newCount >= 4)
        {
            alert("Only 3 Toppings, Please");
            document.toppings;return false;
        }
      }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Variables
      var crust;
      var sauce;
      var smallPrice;
      var medPrice;
      var largePrice;
      var topPrice = 0;
      var finalCost;

      $("#total").click(function() {
        // Size
        var size = $('input:radio[name=size]:checked').val();

        if(size === undefined) {
            alert("What Size Pizza? Please pick an option."); }

        // Sauce
        sauce = $('input:radio[name=sauce]:checked').val();

        if(sauce === undefined) {
            alert("What Sauce Would You Like? Please pick an option."); }

        // Crust Type
        crust = $('input:radio[name=crust]:checked').val();

        if(crust === undefined) {
            alert("What Crust Type? Please pick an option."); }

        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 12;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 14;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 smallPrice = 16;
           }
            //return smallPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 15;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 17;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 medPrice = 21;
           }
            //return medPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
           if ($('#Thin').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 18;
           }
           if ($('#Regular').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 21;
           }
           if ($('#Deep-dish').is(':checked'))
           {
                 largePrice = 26;
           }
            //return largePrice;
        }

        //Calculating Toppings

        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 1;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 2;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 3;
           }
            //return topPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 2;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 4;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 6;
           }
            //return topPrice;
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
           if(newCount = 1)
           {
                topPrice = 3;
           }
           if(newCount = 2)
           {
                topPrice = 6;
           }
           if(newCount = 3)
           {
                topPrice = 9;
           }
            //return topPrice;
        }

        // Calculating the Final Cost with toppings

        if ($('#Small').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (smallPrice + topPrice);
        }
        if ($('#Medium').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (medPrice + topPrice);
        }
        if ($('#Large').is(':checked'))
        {
            finalTotal = (largePrice + topPrice);
        }
            console.log("s " + smallPrice);
            console.log("m " + medPrice);
            console.log("l " + largePrice);
            console.log("top " + topPrice);
            console.log("final " + finalTotal);

            $("#msgHere").html("Your Total is: $ " + finalTotal);
    });
});
</script>
```

Check this updated snippet.

In your code many mistakes are there like
**1.** In JS you are getting elements by ID but you have not give ID to elements.
**2.** Why you are returning `topPrice`, `largePrice` etc from the click event? That is not 
required because your execution will be not continue after return.
**3.** Variable `medPrice` was missing.

Comment: That mostly works, I have some kinks to work out but it fixed my main issue. Much thanks!! @yogesh patel

Comment: I already commented all this under the question. It is not really worth an answer since it is not useful to anyone but OP